# Should we keep 80 characters per line in Java?

Tags: java, coding-style, indentation

There are lots of websites or blogs said that we should keep 80 characters per line in our program since it is relatively to display in some console environment.

However, I found that it is very hard to keep this practice in Java. When we write Java code, we write a function in a class, it requires us to do some indentation already, let alone to add a few if-else statements inside the function.

Apart from that, we always keep call functions in a object. Such kind of behavior make that it is hard to make 80 characters per line.

Wrapping the line is a method, but it decrease the readability of the code.

I am not a professional java programmer. Would you still follow this rule  when writing Java? or is there common practice on the indentation of java?

Comment: You do whatever the coding style says, period ;)

Comment: Consider what happens when wanting to print a hardcopy.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

80 character line length restrictions made sense when we dealt with paper punch cards and small monitors.  I think it makes little sense now that we read code on wider monitors.

I find that nesting and methods have little effect on readability.  If I see nesting that's too deep, it's a suggestion that the cyclomatic complexity of my method is too high - time to decompose.

I don't want to scroll back and forth, but I find that 120 characters is manageable.

Comment: +1 Format code to 80 columns or thereabouts for sending through email or some other media that are more picky about their widths. Otherwise go with what works for you and/or your team. I usually do about 250 myself.

Comment: sounds like there are no strict rule for this.

Comment: Yeah my internal formatter is formatted to produce 120characters too I think. When committing I just let it produce whatever format the coding style says - it's not as if I ever see that version, so that can be 80, 200 or 40 chars ;)

Comment: God help the person that writes 250-length lines of code if I have to work on it.  My 1920 width monitor can comfortably fit two 80 character files side by side with a good font size.  250 characters and I will want to tear my hair out.  Or someone else's.

Comment: You sound like a fun guy to work with, Dan.  Tile horizontally, accept 120 chars, and take a deep breath.

Comment: merging is much easier when you can fit 3 columns on one screen. Unless you have a gigantic monitor, 80 chars is nice for that.

Comment: I hate 80 characters especially when you use long descriptive method and variable names.  Everything is now so wrapped at 80 lines it makes reading it impossible.  I am definitely in favor of 120 at least.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on your environment/team/ways of working. Since all of us have widescreens on our desks we want to use as much screen estate as possible. We have 120 characters and it has worked well for us.

If you are having problems with always filling the 120 characters width I'd say you should look over your code, perhaps some refactoring is in place.